# Understanding Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to understand Scanner class in java, out of some examples trying I am in ambiguity with below two programs, where I dont see any difference logically but output is telling that there is something I am missing. Please help me on this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scanner1.nextLine();
        scanner1.close();

        // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

       // print the next line
       System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

       // check if there is a next line again
       System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextLine());

       // print the next line
       System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

       // check if there is a next line again
       System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextLine());

       // close the scanner
       scanner.close();
       }
```

above program is printing below output

```
Hello World! \n 3+3.0=6
Hello World! \n 3+3.0=6
false
```

While the below program which i dont see any difference with above is showing the different output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="Hello World! \n 3 + 3.0 = 6";
        // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

       // print the next line
       System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

       // check if there is a next line again
       System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextLine());

       // print the next line
       System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

       // check if there is a next line again
       System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextLine());

       // close the scanner
       scanner.close();
       }
```

output of above program is

```
Hello World!
true
3 + 3.0 = 6
false
```

Comment: In the first example you're using `scanner1`, only then `scanner`. Is this a typo?

Comment: I am using two scanner objects in the first example, one is scanner 1 to store input string from keyboard and then parse it with scanner.
In the second example I am directly hardcoding the input string in the program unlike giving it at run time (as in first example)

Answer (score 2):

If \n is written in the file you can't use nextLine() [with two backslash it will give you **java.util.NoSuchElementException**]because there is not \n (end of line) but instead there is \n (two backslash).
To read the file and replace the \n in the text with actual EOL,you can use the sc.useDelimiter("\\n") for new line but then it might break the functionalities of scanner's some method.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("Hello World! \\n 3 + 3.0 = 6");
s.useDelimiter("\\\\n");
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
```

will give you the output like

```
Hello World!
3 + 3.0 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in the first snippet you are typing `Hello World! \n 3+3.0=6` to the standard input. "\n" is not parsed as new line in this case (it is parsed as the character '\' followed by the character 'n'). You have to actually press the enter button after typing "Hello World! " in order for the scanner to split the input into two lines.

On the other hand, when the Scanner takes the input from a String, "\n" is treated as a new line character.

Oh, and it does appear you have a typo in your first snippet. I was assuming you are using a Scanner that takes its input from `System.in` (you probably got the code of the two snippets mixed up).